# Gerar uma distribuição para cada elemento i da minha amostra

Tags: r

Tenho interesse em aplicar esse modelo descrito na variavel `d` para cada um dos 1024 elementos descritos no meu segundo `for` e por fim armazenar os percentis de cada um dessas distribuições em um vetor que chamei de `vetorPercent`.

Acredito que com esse código eu so esteja gerando apenas uma distribuição `d` e nao uma distribuição `d[i]` para cada elemento `i` da minha amostra:

```
precomed = vector(mode = "numeric", length = 1581L)

for (x in 1:1581) {
  precomed[x] = (dados1[x] + dados2[x])/2
}

vetorPercent <- list()

for (i in 1:1024) {

  d <- dados3[i]*rnorm(1024, precomed[i], 
                                      sqrt(var(dados3)))

    vetorPercent[[i]] <- quantile(d, c(.05, .95))
}
```